# styling dynamically loaded elements after plugin initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm new to JavaScript. I have a script which loaded in layout (master page). This script for customization form fields ([Custom forms elements](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)). This [link](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/custom-form-elements.js) to js file.

I have many blocks on the page which are loaded via ajax. Therefore, my elements are sometimes, not styled the way they are supposed to.

**My question**: How to deal with this situation when plugin laoded in main page but target elements loaded later, via ajax?

Comment: The question is not actually a question. They are loaded, so what?

Comment: Because plugin loaded first then target elements not serve this plugin.

Comment: it's really difficult (I'd even say "impossible") to understand what you mean :-S What does mean "elements not serve this plugin"?

Comment: @zerkms: for example we have plugin which make customization(add style, or other) some elements. The plugin loaded before this elements created, therefore, this elements will be without customization. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your styles are applied by applying classes and CSS it should work for ajax-loaded content. But not so if there's a script that applies them.

For that, you need to separate out that part of code and call it on the new elements every time you append some content.

```
$.ajax({
.
.
.

    success:function(data){
      var newElem = $(data);
      target.append(newElem );

      applyStyles(newElem);
    }

});
```